# Measure theory: integrability and limit

Tags: measure-theory

I'm an undergraduate student in math and I've been stuck on the following question for a while. Could anyone help me show that? Thanks.

Given

- a measure space $(X,\mathscr{A} ,\mu) $
- a Borel-measurable function $f:X\rightarrow R$
- $\phi:[0,+\infty]
     \rightarrow[0,+\infty] $a monotone non-decreasing function,

Show that if $\int\phi(|f|)d\mu < + \infty$, then

$ \lim_{a \to \infty } \phi(a)\ \mu(\{x \in X: |f(x)|>a\} = 0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi(a)\mu(|\{x:|f(x)| >a\} \leq \int_{\{x:|f(x)| >a\}}  \phi(|f|)d\mu \to 0$ as $a \to \infty$. The inequality holds because $|f(x)| >a$ implies $\phi(|f(x)|)>\phi(a)$. The last step follows by DCT and the fact that the set $\{x:|f(x)| >a\}$ decreases to empty set as $ a$ increases to $\infty$.

Comment: Ok so I understand the inequality and the fact that that the set decreases to the empty set as “a” increases. But how is the last step a consequence of the DCT? Could you maybe elaborate a bit more ? Thanks.

Comment: If $E_n$ decreases to empty set and $h$ is integrable then $\int_{E_n} h d\mu \to 0$ because you can write $\int_{E_n} h d\mu =\int h I_{E_n} d\mu$, the integrand  $h I_{E_n}$ tends to $0$ and $|h I_{E_n}| \leq |h|$ which is integrable.